# ubuntu: .run file does not work at all

Tags: php, ubuntu, installation, xampp

hey I've got a strange problem, I've read plenty of articles about it on the net and still have no clue what am I doing wrong. Here it goes: I want to build php projects on ubuntu so I got netbeans and wanted to install xampp. I downloaded xamp installer (extension .run) and it doesn't work at all, I mean I tried via terminal and also graphical mode- still nothing. I just run it as it's supposed 2 b run and nothing happens. So I typed in the terminal the following:

```
strace ./<xampp_installer_name>.run
```

and I got something like lot of lines but only this one seems 2 contain some error:

```
open("/lib/ld-linux.so.2", O_RDONLY)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
_exit(127)
```

Does anyone have any idea what I missed or I am doing wrong with this...? It took a day of my life and I'm out so I'd appreciate any ideas.
peace

Answer (score 0):

You might need the 64 bit version of the xampp installer.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who has this problem, rconxs's solution worked for me.  If you're new to Ubuntu, you can check if you'll need the 64 bit version by going to System Settings > Details. On the overview page, check to see if the "OS type" is 64 bit.  If so, be sure to download the 64 bit installer (should have a file name similar to: xampp-linux-**x64**-1.8.3-2-installer.run).  Then, just follow the rest of the instructions on the apache friends site.